# Retrieve Child Object records from other tables values in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

In Service_line_TABLE's, line_on_structure column is "TRUE" then retrieve all the child records. If not just retriew the service line's object record.

the expected result table is given in the attached image.

This is the query i have tried, but not working.

```
SELECT S.contract_id, S.contract_name, L.line_id, O.object_id
FROM Service_Line L, Service_Contract S, Object O
WHERE ( L.contract_id = S.contract_id AND O.object_id = L.object_id )  AND 
      ( ( L.line_on_structure = 'True' AND O.object_id IN ( SELECT object_id
                                                            FROM Object O
                                                            START WITH O.object_id = L.object_id
                                                            CONNECT BY PRIOR O.object_id = O.belongs_to_object AND 
                                                               O.contract = O.belongs_to_site ) ) OR 
                                                               (  L.line_on_structure = 'False' AND O.object_id IN (  
                                                                  SELECT object_id
                                                                  FROM Object O
                                                                  WHERE O.object_id = L.object_id) ) )
```

Comment: have you attempted to write a query, and if so, please post it

Comment: Do not post schema and sample data as images. Use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `Recursive CTE` instead of your query.

```
WITH mycte(object_id,parent_object_id,line_name,line_id,contract_id,name)
AS ( 
     SELECT o.object_id,o.parent_object_id,s.line_name,s.line_id,s.contract_id,c.name
     FROM   ServiceLine s join object o on s.object_id = o.object_id 
                          join contract c on c.contract_id=s.contract_id
     WHERE s.Line_on_structure = 'TRUE' and o.parent_object_id IS NULL

     UNION ALL

     SELECT o.object_id,o.parent_object_id,m.line_name,m.line_id,m.contract_id,m.name
     FROM  mycte m 
     JOIN   object o
     ON m.object_id = o.parent_object_id )

SELECT  CONTRACT_ID,NAME,LINE_ID,LINE_NAME,OBJECT_ID
FROM  mycte m 
UNION ALL
SELECT s.contract_id,c.name,s.line_id,s.line_name,o.object_id
FROM ServiceLine s join object o on s.object_id = o.object_id
                   join contract c on c.contract_id=s.contract_id
WHERE s.Line_on_structure = 'FALSE' and o.parent_object_id IS NULL
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=505b33e4ed86521bb8dab5c855b5a56b)

OUTPUT:

```
+------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| CONTRACT_ID| NAME         | LINE_ID | LINE_NAME | OBJECT_ID |
+------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 100001     | ABC_CONTRACT | 0001    | XYZ       | OBJ1      |
| 100001     | ABC_CONTRACT | 0001    | XYZ       | OBJ2      |
| 100001     | ABC_CONTRACT | 0001    | XYZ       | OBJ3      |
| 100001     | ABC_CONTRACT | 0001    | XYZ       | OBJ4      |
| 100001     | ABC_CONTRACT | 0001    | XYZ       | OBJ5      |
| 100001     | ABC_CONTRACT | 0002    | DFS       | AAA1      |
+------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```